# Workaround for virtual static function functionality

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, virtual

Let's say I have a class:

```
class StateVector {
protected:
    float* _v;

public:

    StateVector():_v(new float[size()]) {}
    virtual ~StateVector() { delete [] _v; }

    virtual size_t size() = 0;

    // ...

};

class PositionState : public StateVector {
public:
    size_t size() { return 3; }
    float* x()    { return _v; }
};

class MovingState : public PositionState {
public:
    size_t size() { return PositionState::size() + 3; }
    float* v()    { return _v + PositionState::size(); }
};
```

The intent here is to allow derived classes to specify the size of the state vector by overriding `size()`. (This information needs to be available to the constructor of `StateVector`, the base class which owns the underlying array).

However, this is less than ideal for a few reasons:

- First, in this implementation, `size()` must/will be the same for all instances of a class. But in this factoring, there is nothing that prevents different instances of the same class from having different opinions about `size()`.
- Second, other classes need to generate an instance in order to query the appropriate size:

  ```
  template <typename State>
  class StateTransition {

      Matrix<float> _m;

      // constructor for Matrix takes #rows, #cols
      StateTransition():_m(State().size(), State().size()) {}

      // ...

  };
  ```

This is silly, because for all `State`s, size() will be the same. In this case, size() might be quite large, and in the constructor for `StateTransition` will (by constructing two `State`s) allocate two arrays of that size and then immediately throw them away!

Finally, it is expected that each derived class will carry a superset of its base's state, so size() should never be smaller for base classes than for derived classes– but since we can't traverse the inheritance tree, I don't know of a way to enforce this programmatically. This is a secondary concern, but it would be nice if there were a clean way to handle it.

It would make the most sense to be able to write:

```
class StateVector {
    float* _v;
    StateVector:_v(new float[size()]) {}

    virtual static size_t size() = 0;
};

class PositionState {
    static size_t size() { return 3; }
    // ...
};

// etc.

template <typename State>
class StateTransition {

    Matrix<float> _m;

    StateTransition():_m(State::size(), State::size()) {}
};
```

However, other answers here (and elsewhere) indicate that virtual static functions are not allowed (and some of them unhelpfully suggest that it "doesn't make sense" or "wouldn't be useful").

What is an idiomatic way to solve this problem, that makes it easy as possible for derived classes to follow the rules?

Comment: Why can't you pass `size` as a parameter in the constructor?

Comment: @KunalPuri How would `StateTransition` get access to that information?

Comment: `virtual` wouldn’t help here. The call to `size()` in the base class’s constructor would call the base class’s version.

Comment: @trbabb Why can't you store that info in the base class by defining data member? and return it whenever required?

Comment: @KunalPuri Because, as per the question, that requires constructing an instance to query the size, which is unnecessarily/arbitrarily expensive.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Aha, good point, didn't catch that; and it makes sense.

The spirit of the question stands, though-- what's a good way to do this?

Comment: Will any client class that is querying for the size, know about the most derived type?

Comment: @JonathonK: Good question, and not necessarily. A `StateTransition<MovingState>`, for example, might work on a `MovingState`, and do something to the first six elements of the state vector; thus it needs to know that the number of elements is (at least) 6. But (for example), an `OrientedState` might derive from `MovingState` and contain more elements (say, four for a quaternion). It is safe for StateTransition<MovingState> to ignore the orientation data, but the base `StateVector` still needs to know that there are 10 total elements.

Comment: You can use templates instead

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure why you insist on using virtual functions and not numeric arguments passed to the constructor of the base class, there is a solution that involves virtual functions, but of a different class:

```
class StateVectorInfo {
public:
  virtual int size() const = 0;
protected:
  ~StateVectorInfo () = default;
};

class PositionStateInfo : public StateVectorInfo {
  PositionStateInfo (); // don't create other instances
public:
  virtual int size() const;
  static PositionStateInfo info; // single instance
};

PositionStateInfo PositionStateInfo::info; // a definition is needed

class StateVector {
    float* _v;
public:
    StateVector (const StateVectorInfo& info):
       _v(new float[info.size()]) {
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not insisting anything be virtual. I only have the requirement that: (a) the most derived class's opinion on size wins, (b) size is uniform for all instances of a class (c) other classes can query the size without constructing an instance. Numeric passing doesn't satisfy (c). If static virtual functions existed, they would satisfy all that. But they don't, so the question is, "what should be done instead?"

Comment: @trbabb "_If static virtual functions existed_" is meaningless as there could be different semantics for these functions. Anyway you can have a virtual function for dynamic queries and a static one for static queries that return the same information. And derived class can have a constructor taking the parameter and passing it to the base class ctor, allowing further derivation.

Comment: But if you insist on using a virtual function on `this` in a constructor, I can propose another solution.

Comment: Passing information from derived to base constructors addresses (a) and possibly (b) in a fragile way, but not (c). If you think all three are satisfied by your solution, can you provide more complete code? It's not clear from your example how the requirements are met. How are derived classes constructed, for example? You do not need to use virtual functions if you can meet the requirements some other way.

Comment: @trbabb If I'm reading his answer correctly, he is suggesting that you define your vector information in singletons, and then your state vector references one of the singletons.  This would allow for a and c in a very straightforward way, b would be enforced on the info class.  It becomes more of a vector has some kind of definition, than a vector defines itself.

Comment: @trbabb Passing parameters through constructors to base classes is a common idiom and usually considered a clean pattern. I have never seen it described as particularly fragile. Rejecting that idiom seems really bizarre.